# Why can I receive Firebase Notifications through the console but not through the server?

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-cloud-messaging

I can receive Firebase notifications when using the console and sending myself a test message through a campaign, but I'm unable to receive notifications when I sent it through the server. I've confirmed that the google-service.json file is correct.

Comment: Since you're using Kotlin, I think that this [resource](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-use-firebase-cloud-messaging-on-android-d92cb4b53cfe) will help. Here is the corresponding [repo](https://github.com/alexmamo/FirebaseCloudMessaging).